# problem with table of contents when I restart chapters counter

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, counters, parts, hyperlink

I am working on some projects and for that, I am using this `\LoadClassWithOptions{memoir}` but the issue is with a table of contents. When I click on chapter 1 of part 2 then it goes to chapter 1 of part 1. To reset chapter counters in part 2, I am using this command. `\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}`. I don't know what could be the reason but this code is working fine in the book document class. I can't upload my complete code as it is pretty lengthy and all that. Kindly let me know someone has any solution for it so that toc goes to the respective chapter.

This is what I want to achieve with accurate toc.

> Part 1
>
> Chapter 1
>
> Chapter 2
>
> Part 2
>
> Chapter 1
>
> Chapter 2
>
> Chapter 3

Thank you

Comment: Redefine \theHchapter so that it gives for every chapter a unique value across the document. E.g. `\renewcommand\theHchapter{\thepart.\thechapter}`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately, it is still not working fine with toc.

Comment: sorry but you didn't provide a sensible example and so you will have to figure out yourself how to make \theHchapter unique. If need print it everywhere to check what its value is.

Comment: Please provide a short MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. It basically needs to include two `\part` macros and the corresponding `\chapter` macros; no text is needed.